# Proving that continuous map from subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$ is closed

Tags: calculus, continuity

Let $\delta>0$ and $f:\mathbb B((0,0),\delta)\to\mathbb R$ is a continuous map, where 
$\mathbb B((0,0),\delta)=\{(x,y) \in \mathbb R^2 \text{ such that } x^2+y^2\leq\delta^2\}$

Prove that there exists $(x_0, y_0)$ belonging to $\mathbb B((0,0),\delta)$ such that $f(x_0, y_0)=\sup f(x,y)$, where $(x,y)$ belongs to $\mathbb B((0,0),\delta)$

How do I approach this problem?

Comment: Hint: image of compact set is a compact set here

Answer (score 3):

**Hint** : a continuous, real-valued function defined on a compact set (*i.e.* closed and bounded set) is bounded and attains its bounds.

Comment: I didn't use the compactness property, but I have managed to show that $f$ is bounded. Where do I take it from there?

Comment: Here, the compactness matters. It is the property you need to use. It gives : $f$ is bounded on $\mathbb{B}\big( (0,0),\delta \big)$ and : there exist $(x_{0},y_{0}) \in \mathbb{B}\big( (0,0),\delta \big)$ such that $\displaystyle \sup \limits_{(x,y) \in \mathbb{B}\big( (0,0),\delta \big)} f(x,y) = f(x_{0},y_{0})$.

Comment: Can you please reference a proof of the compactness property?

Comment: @Diya : See this document, for example : http://www.maths.ox.ac.uk/system/files/coursematerial/2013/2859/9/Chapter_6.pdf

Comment: The problem is, this property makes use of Metric spaces or topological properties. I'm expected to prove this simply using calculus and $\epsilon, \delta$